# SQLiteBlobTooBigException - Huawei devices, Android 9 and 10

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, huawei-mobile-services

I get **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException** only for Huawei family devices, Android 9 and 10

[Crash by devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jeuw.png)

In **onUpgrade** method I want to add new colum to table

```
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
...
        case 43:
               addColumn(db, TABLE_LESSONS, _SPEED_GAME_EASY_FINISHED, " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
               addColumn(db, TABLE_LESSONS, _SPEED_GAME_HARD_FINISHED, " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
               addColumn(db, TABLE_LESSONS, _MEMORY_GAME_EASY_FINISHED, " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
...
}
```

```
    private void addColumn(SQLiteDatabase db, String table, String column, String columnType) {
        boolean isColumnExist = false;
        AbstractWindowedCursor cursor = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " LIMIT 0,1";

        try {
            cursor = getSqlCursorWithIncreasedWindowSize(db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null));

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                isColumnExist = cursor.getColumnIndex(column) != -1;
            }

            if (!isColumnExist) {
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + table + " ADD COLUMN " + column + columnType);
            }

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to increase cursor window size, but it did not help

```
fun getSqlCursorWithIncreasedWindowSize(cursor: Cursor): AbstractWindowedCursor {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val cw = CursorWindow(null, 10000L)
        (cursor as AbstractWindowedCursor).window = cw
    }
    return cursor as AbstractWindowedCursor
}
```

**TABLE_LESSONS** contains 10 columns of integers, longs and short text

Problem occurs in **cursor.moveToFirst()**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3430)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow (SQLiteConnection.java)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteConnection.java:904)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteSession.java:851)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow (SQLiteQuery.java:62)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:149)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount (SQLiteCursor.java:137)
  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition (AbstractCursor.java:220)
  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst (AbstractCursor.java:259)
  at com.kkk.english_words.data.local.db.DatabaseHelper.addColumn (DatabaseHelper.java:31)
  at com.kkk.english_words.data.local.db.DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade (DatabaseHelper.java:161)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:417)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:313)
  at com.kkk.english_words.data.local.db.DatabaseHelper.getDb (DatabaseHelper.java:2)
  at com.kkk.english_words.data.local.db.DatabaseHelper.getActivityTimeDbHelper (DatabaseHelper.java:2)
  at com.kkk.english_words.data.local.db.DatabaseHelper.getActivityTimeDbHelper (DatabaseHelper.java:1)
  at com.kkk.english_words.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:187)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7458)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7448)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1286)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3409)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash doesn't happen when creating the column, it happens when fetching data, which is too big to fit in a Cursor.

If you want to check if a column exists, I suggest querying `sqlite_master` table instead (https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).

As a rule of thumb I don't suggest keeping data in the megabytes in a SQLite single record in Android. If you have no choice than to store this data locally I would suggest you write this data to a file and store its path in the database instead.